# Haworthia fasciata "Zebra Plant" and water?

Tags: houseplants, watering, succulents

I'm posting here a picture for my Haworthia Fasciata, and it's in water for 7 days until now.

[image]

What I've read in blogs and comments of people, is that this plant doesn't support over-watering, but according to my experience. I've seen the inverse, because it's growing.

what are the risks of letting the roots inside water ? can it support living like that? any previous experience ?

Regards

Comment: Roots grown in H20 differ from roots grown in soil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many plants can be grown hydroponically which is what you are doing. And the same plant may not survive in soil that is over watered. The difference lies in the amount of oxygen in the water. If there's enough water movement and surface area the plant may survive longer but you'll need to start adding hydroponic nutrients for it to grow.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to install a submersible or external aquarium pump to add the water circulation ?

Comment: Sure. Just put an air stone in the jar connected to a pump.